# Checking List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to do a schedule that has constraints in Prolog. Scheduling will be based on two constraints. The courses of the same semester and the courses taught by the same instructor cannot be scheduled to the same time slot.

`course(ceng123,1).` 
Course code and semester of course.

`slot(monday,1).` 
Day and hour on day.

`teaches(jack,ceng123).`
Teacher and course code.

```
 course(cse111,1).
 course(cse112,1).
 course(cse113,1).
 course(cse114,1).
 course(cse115,2).
 course(cse116,2).
 course(cse117,2).
 course(cse118,2).
 slot(monday,1).
 slot(monday,2).
 slot(tuesday,1).
 slot(tuesday,2).
 teaches(erkan,cse111).
 teaches(erkan,cse112).
 teaches(erkan,cse113).
 teaches(erkan,cse114).
 teaches(merkan,cse115).
 teaches(merkan,cse116).
 teaches(kan,cse117).
 teaches(kan,cse118).
```

The answer that I expect is:

```
 ?- schedule([cse111,cse112,cse113,cse114,cse115,cse116,cse117,cse118],X).
 X = [cse111, monday, 1, cse112, monday, 2, cse113, tuesday, 1, cse114, tuesday, 2, cse115, monday, 1, cse116, monday, 2, cse117, tuesday, 1, cse118, tuesday, 2]
```

I wrote a code that has no constraints:

```
 course(cse111,1).
 course(cse112,1).
 course(cse113,1).
 course(cse114,1).
 course(cse115,2).
 course(cse116,2).
 course(cse117,2).
 course(cse118,2).
 slot(monday,1).
 slot(monday,2).
 slot(tuesday,1).
 slot(tuesday,2).
 teaches(erkan,cse111).
 teaches(erkan,cse112).
 teaches(erkan,cse113).
 teaches(erkan,cse114).
 teaches(merkan,cse115).
 teaches(merkan,cse116).
 teaches(kan,cse117).
 teaches(kan,cse118).


 schedule([],[]).
 schedule([Course|CourseTail],[Course,Day,Slot|ScheduleTail]):-
     slot(Day,Slot),schedule(CourseTail,ScheduleTail).
```

There is no problem, but when i try this;

```
 course(cse111,1).
 course(cse112,1).
 course(cse113,1).
 course(cse114,1).
 course(cse115,2).
 course(cse116,2).
 course(cse117,2).
 course(cse118,2).
 slot(monday,1).
 slot(monday,2).
 slot(tuesday,1).
 slot(tuesday,2).
 teaches(erkan,cse111).
 teaches(erkan,cse112).
 teaches(erkan,cse113).
 teaches(erkan,cse114).
 teaches(merkan,cse115).
 teaches(merkan,cse116).
 teaches(kan,cse117).
 teaches(kan,cse118).     

 schedule([],[]).
 schedule([Course|CourseTail],[Course,Day,Slot|ScheduleTail]):-
     schedule(CourseTail,ScheduleTail), check(Course,Day,Slot,ScheduleTail).

 check(_, _, _,[]).
 check(Course,Day,Slot,[Course2,Day2,Slot2|Tail]):- check(Course,Day,Slot,Tail),
     course(Course,Semester1),course(Course2,Semester2),Semester1=\=Semester2, 
     slot(Day,Slot),slot(Day2,Slot2).
```

I tried to write constraint but I took an error.

```
 uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:4) . or operator expected           after expression'),read_term/3)
```

Can you see the mistake?

Comment: It `gave an error`? Please post the error, always give as much information as possible.

Comment: It said C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/deneme.pl:27: warning: singleton variables [Course,Day,Slot] for check/4 Then answered "no"

Answer (score 3):

Singleton variable is a variable which is mentioned only once in the program: [See wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_variable). You get that for line 27 which I presume is this one:  `check(Course,Day,Slot,[])`. You can replace it with  `check(_, _, _,[])`. ('_' means any variable. This means you can universally quantify the variables.)

You do not get an error. Prolog saying no just means that your constraints cannot be satisfied.

Comment: When i edited as you say and run, it says ?- schedule([cse111,cse112,cse113,cse114,cse115,cse116,cse117,cse118],X).
uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:4) . or operator expected after expression'),read_term/3)

Comment: What Prolog are you using? It is very common to use '_'. http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/SingletonVar.html Are you sure you get this error now, and got just a warning before?

Comment: I use SWI, i edited as you said, after i run again it said uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:4) . or operator expected after expression'),read_term/3) –

Comment: `schedule([cse111,cse112,cse113,cse114,cse115,cse116,cse117,cse118],X).
X = [cse111, monday, 1, cse112, monday, 1, cse113, monday, 1|...] .`. This is what I get when I run your code with my changes.

Comment: My aim is cse111 and cse112 must have different hourses like [cse111, monday, 1, cse112, monday, 2].

Comment: When i run this i obtained as you wrote.  course(cse111,1).
 course(cse112,1).
 course(cse113,1).
 course(cse114,1).
 course(cse115,2).
 course(cse116,2).
 course(cse117,2).
 course(cse118,2).
 slot(monday,1).
 slot(monday,2).
 slot(tuesday,1).
 slot(tuesday,2).
 teaches(erkan,cse111).
 teaches(erkan,cse112).
 teaches(erkan,cse113).
 teaches(erkan,cse114).
 teaches(merkan,cse115).
 teaches(merkan,cse116).
 teaches(kan,cse117).
 teaches(kan,cse118).


 schedule([],[]).
 schedule([Course|CourseTail],[Course,Day,Slot|ScheduleTail]):-
     slot(Day,Slot),schedule(CourseTail,ScheduleTail).

Comment: I have two constraints. Two courses in an hour cannot have same semester number and same teacher's courses will not be in same hour. My goal is these statements.

Comment: How can i compare them, do u have an idea?

Comment: What predicate do you use to define the hour in which a course is held? In your current constraints you do not model the teacher constraint at all. You can define the teachers constraint in terms of a predicate itself by writing `teaches_at(teacher, course, slot)` which enforces the constraints you mentioned and then use it in your check predicate, by ensuring that there exists a teacher which teaches the course at that slot.

Comment: slot predicate is slot(day,hour). Hour is coming from slot. You are true, first i want to see only semester constraint, but i couldn't. How can i write it in check predicate, my check is not working.

Comment: can you see the mistake in semester constraint check predicate?

Comment: `check(Course,Day,Slot,[Course2,Day2,Slot2|Tail]):- check(Course,Day,Slot,Tail),
     course(Course,Semester1),course(Course2,Semester2),Semester1=\=Semester2, 
     slot(Day,Slot),slot(Day2,Slot2).` This gives you a syntax error or do you not get any answers?

Comment: After i write ?-schedule... It says uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:1 (char:4) . or operator expected after expression'),read_term/3)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by clearly defining your constraints. 
From your comments, I read:
**Two courses in an hour cannot have same semester number and same teacher's courses will not be in same hour.**

Therefore you can assign a schedule to a course when it fulfills those requirements, hinting that you have to know which assignments have been already issued. So you can create a procedure that keeps the current schedule and only add a new assignment when your requirements are met.

So, start by defining your `schedule/2` procedure that calls a new procedure `schedule/3` with an empty list:

```
schedule(Courses,Schedule):-
   schedule(Courses, [], Schedule).
```

Now, this procedure has on the first argument the list of courses to assign a schedule, keeps the current assignments con the second argument and unifies the third argument with the final Schedule (with the data you require, that is Course, Day and Slot).
I'll use a structure to represent each assignment `schedule(Course, Day, Slot)` because just mixing those datum in a list is not a good idea.

```
schedule([], _, []).
schedule([Course|CourseTail], Courses, [schedule(Course,Day,Slot)|ScheduleTail]):-
% Two courses in an hour cannot have same semester number and same teacher's courses will not be in same hour.
     course(Course, Semester),
     teaches(Teacher, Course),
     slot(Day, Slot),
     \+ member(s(Day, Slot, Semester, _), Courses),
     \+ member(s(Day, Slot, _, Teacher), Courses),
     schedule(CourseTail, [s(Day, Slot, Semester, Teacher)|Courses], ScheduleTail).
```

First clause is the base case. It states that when there are no more courses in the input list, then the schedule will be empty.

Second clause takes the first Course from the input list and computes a possible Semester, Theacher and Day/Slot for that course, and then just checks if the constraints are met. It tests whether there is already a schedule for that Day/Slot/Semester and whether there is already an assignment for the Teacher at that Day/Slot. If the requirements are met then we add this assignment to the list of current assignments and continue recursion.

Upon return, we add the Course/Day/Slot to the list of the final Schedule.